# Mouse buttons have changed

Tags: mouse, mouse-pointer

I have a Srocker V5 mouse that has preset volume buttons on the side of the mouse. These buttons have randomly changed to only work when Im in a browser. They buttons will go forward and backword between web pages. Is there any way to restore the default settings? Im somewhat of a noob to ubuntu, so please bear with me.

Comment: That is usually the default behavior for those side buttons and according to the internets so is the case of your Srocker V5. *If* they were working as volume buttons before then probably you did something to remap them ?!?

Comment: Im not sure how I would have done that.

Comment: Well, I'm sure the default behavior is back/forward buttons in any desktop OS and the answer below says the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually any mouse with extra buttons are by default mapped to IE Backwards and IE Forwards. Probably the solution is a "driver" or additional software, that is used to remap the buttons. I have a Trust GXT 158 and the buttons by default came to the page back and forward, but I have a software to remap them. If the mouse comes with on-board memory then the remapped buttons should stay for as long as you will change then again, but if before you used some kind of daemon then you have to also install it in Linux or ask someone better than me at python to make you a script that sees the IE Forwards and sends the volume up/down and vise versa.